# Hibernate dependency breaks spring boot app

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am currently making a demo app for proof of concept. I have no problem getting the application to run without hibernate, using direct database queries with java.sql.Connection etc. However, as soon as I add in the dependency for "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" the app will no longer run. I get the error:

```
2019-11-22 16:27:44.575  INFO 11484 --- [           main] c.h.app.HibernateDemoApplication         : Starting HibernateDemoApplication on Hal with PID 11484 (C:\Users\Randal\eclipse-workspace\Hibernate-demo\target\classes started by Randal in C:\Users\Randal\eclipse-workspace\Hibernate-demo)
2019-11-22 16:27:44.579  INFO 11484 --- [           main] c.h.app.HibernateDemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-22 16:27:45.376  INFO 11484 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-11-22 16:27:45.405  INFO 11484 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-11-22 16:27:45.765  INFO 11484 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-22 16:27:46.074  INFO 11484 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2019-11-22 16:27:46.101  INFO 11484 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-22 16:27:46.101  INFO 11484 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-11-22 16:27:46.435  INFO 11484 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2019-11-22 16:27:46.443  INFO 11484 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-22 16:27:46.443  INFO 11484 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1806 ms
2019-11-22 16:27:46.599  INFO 11484 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-22 16:27:46.737  INFO 11484 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (null)
2019-11-22 16:27:46.737 ERROR 11484 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query (null).
2019-11-22 16:27:46.740  WARN 11484 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2019-11-22 16:27:46.744  INFO 11484 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-11-22 16:27:46.760  INFO 11484 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-22 16:27:46.773 ERROR 11484 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.hibernatedemo.app.HibernateDemoApplication.main(HibernateDemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkValidationSupport(PoolBase.java:450) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:433) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:402) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:355) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222-4-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222-4-redhat]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222-4-redhat]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222-4-redhat]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I have checked several posts on multiple forums and none of the solutions seem to apply.
Again, the code works perfectly fine when I comment out the dependency for SPRING-JPA. Then it breaks again when I put it back in. I know that the connection works, because I am using the application.properties entries for the parameters when directly querying the database.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hibernatedemo.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hibernate-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Hibernate-demo</name>
    <description>Test Application for family website</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- This is a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSTL tag lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- May Need this to compile JSP, if tomcat-embed-jasper version is not 
            working -->
        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency -->

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is my application.properties:

```
#Welcome Message
welcome.message: Hello World!!!

#Configure Port# for web application
server.port=8083

#Configuration for the servlet
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.date-format=MM/dd/yyyy

#Enter settings for database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/HB_Tutorial
spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=hibernate_demo
spring.datasource.password=hibernate_demo
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        </dependency>

 remove that . This is what causing the problems, not hibernate

Comment: Everything works just fine when I comment out the hibernate dependency... I leave the JTDS in and it works fine. Without it, I have no jdbs driver. I tried using the Microsoft driver and had the same results

Comment: tried running it without the JTDS just to see what would happen... got a new error instead

Comment: That does not matter JDTS is causing the NPE not hibernate.

Comment: *Everything works just fine when I comment out the hibernate dependency* evertything will work just fine other way around - if you remote JDTS (obviously if youy have no other direct dependencies)\

Comment: OK. So, if HAVING the JDTS dependency is breaking hibernate, and REMOVING it causes a DIFFERENT error message... then I am still kinda at square one...

Comment: again, its not braking hibernate. JDST is broken.

Comment: OK... So, it is fixed now... But, I can not credit you for it, since this is a comment and not an "Answer". Turns out that MS driver was not working because I forgot to fix the spring.datasource.url to match the correct driver format... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!

Comment: No problem, answer created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove JDTS from your dependencies as it is causing NPE. It is not Hibernate's fault but a faulty implementation of JDTS.